# How to extract before and after 10 character of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

From a dataframe I need to extract the exact match and its before and after 10 char.

```
Search        Text                                                              parts
boy named     A boy named Alex.He lives in....                                A boy named ale
Jenny       Girl named Jennying as Jenny. This girl is really nice long.....  nnying as Jenny. This gir
```

I tried the below code:

```
part= []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

        c=row['text'].lower().split().count(row['Search'].lower())
        idx = row['text'].lower().find(row['Search'].lower())

        if idx<10:           
            substr = row['text'][:idx+len(row['Search'])+10]
        else:
            subs = row['text'][idx-10:idx+len(row['Search'])+10]    
        part.append(substr)

df['parts'] = part
```

If I am using split() it gives correct result for single word exact match but for combined word like "boy named" it gives count zero.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Can you please rewrite?

Comment: @S3DEV edited can you check?